# Sequelize - How to set association, save entity and return the saved entity with the associated entity

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to create an association between an existing (user) entity and save the new entity (visit).

I've read the sequelize docs and can't see a better way of doing this than saving the first entity using async/await, then fetching it again passing `include` as an option. See below.

```
export const createVisit = async(req, res) => {
  req.assert('BusinessId', 'Must pass businessId').notEmpty();
  req.assert('UserId', 'Must pass customerId').notEmpty();

  const visit = await new Visit({
    UserId: req.body.UserId,
    BusinessId: req.body.BusinessId,
    redemption: false,
  })
  .save()
   .catch((error) => {
    res.status(400).send({ error });
  });

    const visitWithUser = await Visit.findById(visit.id, {include: [{model: User, attributes: ['firstName','lastName','facebook', 'gender','email']}]})

    res.status(200).send({ visit: visitWithUser })
};
```

Is there a way to save the entity and get sequelize to return the saved entity along with any associations?

Comment: Currently I think this is the only way to go about this. There's an [issue on github](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3807) that's asking to support this functionality.

Comment: Ok - Thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: @Powderham, will you please check the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it supports this feature , as per **[the doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-create)** , you can do it like this :

```
Visit.create({
    UserId: req.body.UserId,
    BusinessId: req.body.BusinessId,
    redemption: false,
}, {
  include: [User]
}).then(function(comment) {
    console.log(comment.user.id);
});
```

Here is the **[git discussion](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3807)** if you want to read.

Comment: I was initially hesitant to step away from using new, but this causes later problems with using new for a side effect: [link](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-new) Therefore I can accept this as the answer